# How can I stop repeating backing?

Tags: android-activity, android, back-stack

I'm developing an application with more than 3 classes. My app is working like this:

I jumped from main activity to another class and then to 3-rd class and came back to 2-nd class and then to 3-rd class again.

My problem was when I pressed the back button when I was in 3-rd it went to 2-nd and then to 3-rd and came again to 2-nd then to 1-st then to home.

I want to stop this process.

Comment: What is the intended behavior of your app? Do you want it to go home from any of the 3 screens? Or move "back" in a certain order (e.g. Main -> 2 -> 3)?

Comment: This is the expected behavior. You can set for 2 and 3 `singleTop` and `FLAG_CLEAR_ON_LAUNCH`. You should study before anything else how Android [stack works](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: While you are reading about stacks as @gunar suggested, have a look at the [Navigation Design](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) docs, just to be sure you aren't making things too hard for yourself and your users.

Comment: once you start sorting this out using the suggestions gunar and Chilledrat gave, assuming you are using Eclipse, you can watch the apps behavior via the Device window in the DDMS section (top right corner menu)... there you will see how many instances of these screens you have running. Keep in mind too that 'home' and 'back' can behave differently depending on how you code this. You can intercept the back click, but that's not likely the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is when you came back to second class from third class, you didn't destroy third class instance. Probably you just started a new Activity, like startActivity(second class). Every time you switched to another class, you create a new Activity instance without destroy previous one. Doing this repeatedly, many Activity instances were kept in task stack. If you don't wanna repeat, you have to destroy previous activity, or change your implementation. You can create a customized stack by yourself, and add or remove Class instances as a view not activity. so 1->(add)2->(add)3->(remove 3)2->(add)3->(remove 3)2->(remove 2)1.

Answer (score 0):

Use     finish() in onStop() method